# How to make production ready Angular Dotnet Core Docker App

Tags: .net, angular, docker

We are trying to make a Docker container, that has a .Net App Server and Angular client

the structure of the project is
ReportBackEnd/
 -some default .net core dirs/
 - angular/

We have created the following Docker file

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
# Setup NodeJs
RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install -qq -y wget && \
    apt-get install -qq -y gnupg2 && \
    wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -qq -y build-essential nodejs && \
    apt-get install -qq -y nginx
# End setup

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
# Setup NodeJs
RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install -qq -y wget && \
    apt-get install -qq -y gnupg2 && \
    wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -qq -y build-essential nodejs && \
    apt-get install -qq -y nginx
# End setup
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ReportBackEnd.csproj", "ReportBackEnd/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ReportBackEnd/ReportBackEnd.csproj"

COPY ["angular/package.json", "ReportBackEnd/angular/"]

RUN cd ReportBackEnd/angular \
    && npm i --silent

COPY . ./
WORKDIR /src/ReportBackEnd
RUN dotnet build "ReportBackEnd.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ReportBackEnd.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ReportBackEnd.dll"]
```

Running this file from Visual Studio's Docker button works as expected.

However when we try to build it and run it ourselves we get:

**Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point**

the commands we use are:

```
docker build -f "C:\<dirs>\ReportBackEnd\Dockerfile" -t core:dev --target base
docker run -dt -p 80:80 core:dev
```